# add asian language support in win form application

Tags: .net, winforms, unicode, c#-3.0, multilingual

how to add asian language support in winform application
using c#?
does it possible without using east asian language support from control pannel?

any help is really appritiated.

Comment: How do you propose that Windows be able to display the East Asian languages without installing support for them first? No matter what you do, your application is going to be limited to at least the languages whose characters the host operating system can display properly.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't require a lot of work from your end.  A user that speaks an East Asian language also has a machine that is capable of displaying the glyphs that are used in her language.  Of course.  Microsoft distributes fonts with different glyph sets on different language versions of Windows.

You do typically want to localize your form so that button and label captions make sense to the user.  That's well supported by resources stored in satellite assemblies.  You simply set the Localizable property of the form to true, use Language to switch to the language you want to support and change the Text properties.  Which isn't actually simple unless you also master the language.  A localization service can help you with that.  That costs money, not a heck of a lot.

You do want to make sure your form autoscales properly.  East Asian machines often use a larger system font to make the intricate glyphs more readable.  An MSDN subscription can get you all the different language versions of Windows that you want to support.  Recommended, troubleshooting layout problems with screenshots is no fun.

Comment: but the fonts such as arial supports unicode as well as what about using rich textbox

Comment: means what about using rich text box in application?